# What constitutes an appropriate use of ref in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ref

Can someone explain how ref is used in React? I understand it's a shortcut that sort of defeats the purpose of the react DOM, but I don't know how or why exactly. I'm trying to determine whether something I'm trying to accomplish represents one of the rare cases where you should use ref

I want a custom bootstrap alert I can show from any of these pages, without using JQuery (I have one working with JQuery already)

I have a router that switches between pages, each containing a Layout component with a Page component inside (based on [this](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-static-boilerplate))
Like:

```js
render() {
  return (<Layout ref={layout => (this.layout = layout)}>
    <WhateverPage
      session={this.session}
      otherExampleProp={"something"}
      showAlert={this.showAlert}/>
  </Layout>);
}

showAlert(type, text, hasTimeout, timeoutMs) {
  this.layout.alert.showAlert(type, text, hasTimeout, timeoutMs);
}
```

I can think of three solutions:

1. Use ref, which as I only partially understand defeats the purpose of react components to some extent, but I'm not sure how exactly...
2. Use ref, but to a lesser extent, by placing the alert component in each Layout before the Page component (so no need for a ref to ).
3. Create a component and a function on each page, using the page's state to control the alert, so it would be basically the same as creating a unique alert for each page, which also defeats the purpose of a component...

The example most people give when explaining what to use ref for involves focus() - is this similar? Intuitively it feels like I should use ref, but I also know that theoretically you shouldn't, but I want to understand why, because there are exceptions and for all I know this may count.

Similarly, I want to create a confirm component to replace the native JS confirm() (since it might be deprecated soon), and this approach (using ref) also makes this WAY easier than creating a component for each page, since I can pass any function as a parameter to the confirm component for it to execute on an OK button press (also gives me the option of including icons, titles, custom buttons, etc).

Existing examples and libraries all seem to use method 3 (or they're simpler, and not not really analogous).

Is ref ok to use here? Is it wrong? Why? Am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you are "misusing" `ref` here because you're trying to build around how React is intended to be used.

`ref` is mainly for accessing the actual rendered DOM element - maybe to focus it, read input, get dimensions, whatever. *Generally speaking* though you should us `ref` as a "read only" feature - use it to get info about the rendered DOM but don't use it as part of a process to bypass `render()` or inject elements into the DOM.

What you should do is create a reusable component for your Alert. Make it flexible enough that it can accept arbitrary settings like color, text, duration, callback functions for accept/cancel/clear, etc. Then you can just render it somewhere, maybe like this:

```
<MyAlert
    title="foo"
    text="bar"
    duration={5}
    confirmCallback={someFunction}
    cancelCallback={anotherFunction}
/>
```

Remember that components are a way to render and interact with `state`, and that's exactly what you're trying to do with your Alert. There is some kind of notification, it has content and controls for doing some action(s), and all of that should live somewhere in your app state hierarchy. There is absolutely no reason to resort to `ref`in this situation.

Comment: Ok, I believe you but I hate agreeing with something without understanding exactly why I should... can you explain why in a little more detail? Does it basically load a bunch of redundant information into memory? Is React smart enough to only update relevant parts of the DOM if I change the state, like the parts specific to my alert, so that isn't as heavy a burden on memory, and generally faster?

Comment: Also, where can I put the alert, and how do I show it? I still can't figure it out...

Comment: ok, maybe I don't agree... using ref works perfectly and it doesn't slow things down noticeably, and it just "feels" right. I really don't understand why I shouldn't use it, AND I'm not sure I can accomplish the same thing with props... if only I could send a function directly from Layout to WhateverPage as a prop...

Comment: @AndrewTorr You're certainly free to do whatever works best for you. But misusing `ref` can easily bite you in the ass. The React documentation itself describes it as a "safety hatch" to use sparingly. The more complicated your app becomes, the more likely it is that using `ref` will have unintended consequences. And in your case you can *absolutely* accomplish what you're trying to do entirely without `ref` - and quite easily, too. Can you explain what you mean by "if only I could send a function directly from Layout to WhateverPage"?

Comment: @AndrewTorr https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#dont-overuse-refs

Comment: "misusing ref can easily bite you in the ass"
This is the part I want to be clearer on - how?

"the more likely it is that using ref will have unintended consequences"
And this - can you give me a simple example?

Comment: By the way, I've decided to just put the alert on each page, and to create a showAlert function on each page. I don't like doing it that way because if I want to change how it works I have to change every one of those instances instead of just changing the function in the alert component, but I've kept it pretty simple otherwise

Comment: "Can you explain what you mean by 'if only I could send a function directly from Layout to WhateverPage'?"
Yes, I mean each route has an index.js that renders a <Layout> component with whatever page component inside it (like the example above). It's part of the boilerplate we're using. I would put the alert in the Layout component and then just pass it as a prop to the page but you can't pass props to the page from Layout because it's set up that way.

Answer (score 0):

To complement the jered answer:

If you plan to use the alert component in all the pages then instead of placing an alert component inside each page you can create a high order component named like PageWithAlert (I would say just Page) that includes the alert component for each page.

You might want to take a look at this https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/higher-order-components.html